# Group_by data frame then divide numeric columns by row means

Tags: r, database, group-by

I have a data frame which looks like the following. I would like to `group_by` by `Group`, then calculate the `rowMeans` of `R1` and `R2` variables when `Position` == "`position_1`" (in the case of A group, the calculated value is 1.935561 and in the case of B Group, the value is 1.30338), followed by dividing `R1` and `R2` by the calculated `rowMeans` for each group. I was trying to run the following code but got an error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue with mirror changes to the original code (e.g., no need to transform the data frame to a longer format)? Thanks for any help!

```
test <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with("R"), ~ .x/ rowMeans(.x %>% filter(Position == "position_1") %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("R")), na.rm = T)))
```

The error message:

```
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
i The error occurred in group 1: Group = "A".
```

Original df:

```
> my_df
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   Group Position       R1     R2
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     position_1 1.94   1.93  
 2 A     position_2 1.92   1.94  
 3 A     position_3 1.50   1.44  
 4 A     position_4 1.63   1.73  
 5 A     position_5 1.37   1.32  
 6 A     position_6 0.324  0.356 
 7 A     position_7 0.144  0.145 
 8 A     position_8 0.107  0.0770
 9 A     position_9 0.0681 0.0618
10 B     position_1 1.42   1.19  
11 B     position_2 1.59   1.47  
12 B     position_3 1.13   1.09  
13 B     position_4 1.45   1.27  
14 B     position_5 1.45   1.24  
15 B     position_6 0.919  0.866 
16 B     position_7 0.601  0.786 
17 B     position_8 0.276  0.553 
18 B     position_9 0.167  0.533 

 structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Position = c("position_1", 
    "position_2", "position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", 
    "position_7", "position_8", "position_9", "position_1", "position_2", 
    "position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", "position_7", 
    "position_8", "position_9"), R1 = c(1.93682154090573, 1.91856596758703, 
    1.49858450015508, 1.63084469573099, 1.37215468874851, 0.324435564944789, 
    0.143752050868138, 0.106781932917991, 0.0680590581417462, 1.41897401502389, 
    1.58660492722105, 1.13036771612536, 1.44662711984727, 1.45416934674475, 
    0.919179924031544, 0.600901176433165, 0.275888860745681, 0.167286913827297
    ), R2 = c(1.9343002335802, 1.93865578506416, 1.44482785753871, 
    1.72787733301708, 1.31512320353745, 0.355672021297666, 0.144683081118674, 
    0.0770487437127792, 0.061811741133288, 1.18778573693332, 1.47211785392794, 
    1.09160495952408, 1.27155041680802, 1.23843099839242, 0.866062777290239, 
    0.786331686244975, 0.553327119553047, 0.53278845132597)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My final df:

```
> final_df
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   Group Position       R1     R2
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     position_1 1.00   0.999 
 2 A     position_2 0.991  1.00  
 3 A     position_3 0.774  0.746 
 4 A     position_4 0.843  0.893 
 5 A     position_5 0.709  0.679 
 6 A     position_6 0.168  0.184 
 7 A     position_7 0.0743 0.0747
 8 A     position_8 0.0552 0.0398
 9 A     position_9 0.0352 0.0319
10 B     position_1 1.09   0.911 
11 B     position_2 1.22   1.13  
12 B     position_3 0.867  0.838 
13 B     position_4 1.11   0.976 
14 B     position_5 1.12   0.950 
15 B     position_6 0.705  0.664 
16 B     position_7 0.461  0.603 
17 B     position_8 0.212  0.425 
18 B     position_9 0.128  0.409 

structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Position = c("position_1", 
"position_2", "position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", 
"position_7", "position_8", "position_9", "position_1", "position_2", 
"position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", "position_7", 
"position_8", "position_9"), R1 = c(1.00065125351551, 0.991219583152912, 
0.774237805036926, 0.842569516399114, 0.708918338790927, 0.167618362296404, 
0.074268933331545, 0.0551684668775569, 0.0351624454831164, 1.08868788459535, 
1.21730034772748, 0.86725875502567, 1.10990434090386, 1.115691008566, 
0.705227887516721, 0.461032988409493, 0.211671853753841, 0.128348535214057
), R2 = c(0.999348629973531, 1.00159890856664, 0.746464646445505, 
0.892701047922063, 0.679453245615846, 0.183756554971745, 0.0747499464592819, 
0.0398069312787244, 0.0319347936506718, 0.911311925097299, 1.1294617486289, 
0.837518574417343, 0.975579199318708, 0.950168790676873, 0.664474502670164, 
0.603301942829393, 0.424532461410369, 0.408774456663421)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you please clarify about when Position == position_1?  Because within A group and within B group there's only one row for each group where Position == position_1, so it implies a rowMeans of just one data point?  Can you illustrate how you make the manual calculation perhaps?

Comment: @Soren Thanks for your comment and question! Yes, for each group, I would like to divide `R1` and `R2` by a single value (row mean from the position_1 row). Basically, I was trying to normalize the data so the mean values in the position_1 equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
final_df = my_df %>% 
           pivot_longer(cols = 3:4) %>% 
           group_by(Group, Position) %>% 
           summarise(mean = mean(value), across()) %>% 
           pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
           mutate(R1 = R1 / mean,
                  R2 = R2 / mean)
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. Actually, the data looks completely different. Now each row has the same mean value of 1. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not so elegant solution that corrects my first answer. Hope this helps you in some way!

```
`final_df = my_df %>% 
           pivot_longer(cols = 3:4) %>% 
           group_by(Group, Position) %>% 
           summarise(mean = mean(value), across()) %>% 
           pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
           mutate(R1 = case_when(Group == "A" ~ (R1 / .$mean[.$Group == "A" & .$Position == "position_1"]),
                                 Group == "B" ~ (R1 / .$mean[.$Group == "B" & .$Position == "position_1"])),
                  R2 = case_when(Group == "A" ~ (R2 / .$mean[.$Group == "A" & .$Position == "position_1"]),
                                 Group == "B" ~ (R2 / .$mean[.$Group == "B" & .$Position == "position_1"])))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "original df" structure provided above and the data.table library, the solution as follows: to take a subset of the original data based on rows corresponding to the desired "position 1", then find the mean value of R1 and R2, grouping by Group; and then doing an inner join on the two tables using the Group as they key, then creating new output variables of the R1 and R2 columns divided by the means given in position 1 data set.  I also created a new position column programmatically, in case this may also be useful.

```
library(data.table)

x<-structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                         "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Position = c("position_1", 
                                                                                         "position_2", "position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", 
                                                                                         "position_7", "position_8", "position_9", "position_1", "position_2", 
                                                                                         "position_3", "position_4", "position_5", "position_6", "position_7", 
                                                                                         "position_8", "position_9"), R1 = c(1.93682154090573, 1.91856596758703, 
                                                                                                                             1.49858450015508, 1.63084469573099, 1.37215468874851, 0.324435564944789, 
                                                                                                                             0.143752050868138, 0.106781932917991, 0.0680590581417462, 1.41897401502389, 
                                                                                                                             1.58660492722105, 1.13036771612536, 1.44662711984727, 1.45416934674475, 
                                                                                                                             0.919179924031544, 0.600901176433165, 0.275888860745681, 0.167286913827297
                                                                                         ), R2 = c(1.9343002335802, 1.93865578506416, 1.44482785753871, 
                                                                                                   1.72787733301708, 1.31512320353745, 0.355672021297666, 0.144683081118674, 
                                                                                                   0.0770487437127792, 0.061811741133288, 1.18778573693332, 1.47211785392794, 
                                                                                                   1.09160495952408, 1.27155041680802, 1.23843099839242, 0.866062777290239, 
                                                                                                   0.786331686244975, 0.553327119553047, 0.53278845132597)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                           -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
setDT(x)


x[,new_position:=1:.N,by=.(Group)]
position1_means <- x[new_position==1,.(Group,R1,R2)]
position1_means[,rowMeans:=mean(c(R1,R2)),by=.(Group)]
final_df <- x[position1_means,
              .(Group,
                new_position,
                R1,
                R2,
                R1_by_p1means=R1/rowMeans,
                R2_by_p1means=R2/rowMeans),
              on=.(Group)]
```

The resulting joined data.table "new_x" output values correspond to those in the given "final df"